# Android Custom Auth with Lambdas

Tags: android, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I am trying to implement a custom auth flow using Amazon Cognito and lambda scripts. The custom authentication is triggered but the request session array is empty instead of triggering the SRP_a challenge like it does using the javascript sdk. If the SRP_a challenge does not happen, it does not perform the PASSWORD_VERIFIER challenge which is necessary for the username/password being used to authenticate. Note: the custom portion of the authentication happens after the username/password auth happens.

Cognito's documentation says that this flow is possible on javascript, iOS and Android but only provides examples in javascript. Below I have included the the Android code that is doing the authentication.

```
    CognitoHelper cognitoHelper = CognitoHelper.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
    username = loginView.getUsername();
    //Must use toLowerCase to make the username not case sensitive
    cognitoHelper.setUser(username.toLowerCase());
    password = loginView.getPassword();
    AuthFlowType authFlowType = AuthFlowType.fromValue(String.valueOf(AuthFlowType.CUSTOM_AUTH));
    HashMap<String, String> authenticationParameters = new HashMap<>();
    authenticationParameters.put(CognitoServiceConstants.AUTH_PARAM_PASSWORD,password);
    authenticationParameters.put(CognitoServiceConstants.AUTH_PARAM_USERNAME, username);

    SRP_aHelper srp_aHelper = new SRP_aHelper(cognitoHelper.getUserPoolID());
    authenticationParameters.put(CognitoServiceConstants.AUTH_PARAM_SRP_A,srp_aHelper.getA().toString(16));

    InitiateAuthRequest initiateAuthRequest = new InitiateAuthRequest();
    initiateAuthRequest.setClientId(cognitoHelper.getClientID());
    initiateAuthRequest.setAuthFlow(authFlowType);
    initiateAuthRequest.setAuthParameters(authenticationParameters);

    CognitoUser cognitoUser = cognitoHelper.getUserPool().getUser(username);
    thisDevice = cognitoUser.thisDevice();
    //getCIPClient returns a AmazonCognitoIdentityProviderClient
    InitiateAuthResult initiateAuthResult = cognitoHelper.getCipClient().initiateAuth(initiateAuthRequest);
```